# average of one columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, average

Here is my file format. I am trying to average on column but I am getting error which is shown in below. Can any one give me some suggestion about it?

The file format is:

```
      0.000      -2953.187     -11363.859     -14317.047
    500.000      -3178.028     -11301.687     -14479.715
   1000.000      -2973.863     -11309.533     -14283.396
   1500.000      -2964.465     -11294.120     -14258.584
   2000.000      -3066.929     -11240.302     -14307.231
   2500.000      -3156.522     -11223.589     -14380.111
   3000.000      -3230.069     -11573.224     -14803.293
```

The script is:

```
import numpy as np
file = open('energy_MM.xvg', 'r')

x = []

for line in file: 
    cols=line.split()[1]
    x.append(float(cols[0]))
numpy.mean(x)
```

the error is:

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "binding.py", line 10, in <module>
            x.append(float(cols[0]))
            ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'
```

Comment: Why are you not using pandas?

Comment: Pandas is a powerful tool, and would work well here.  But, that does not answer the OP's question.  You have something going on in your data file.  At some point you have a space followed by a dash followed by another space, which causes the ValueError to be thrown when trying to convert to float.  Try adding a print statement before the float conversion to see what "x" is, or run you script in a Python interpreter and work from there.  What you are doing should work, but your file is most likely not consistently formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('energy_MM.xvg', sep="\s+", header=None)
df.mean()
```

which will output the following:

```
0     1500.000000
1    -3074.723286
2   -11329.473429
3   -14404.196714
dtype: float64
```

where the left-column corresponds to the column names within the file, which are assigned to integers starting from 0 by using the `header=None` option.

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you very much.